# How to schedule pods on Kubernetes master?

Tags: kubernetes

In my Kubernetes cluster, I have 3 worker node and 1 master node. I have removed the taint on the master node so the k8s can schedule pods on that node.

[image]

Now, I want to change 2 of 3 workers to master and control-plane (can schedule pods on these nodes)node by using the following :

```
kubectl label nodes node1 kubernetes.io/role=master
kubectl label nodes node1 kubernetes.io/role=control-plane
kubectl label nodes node2 kubernetes.io/role=master
kubectl label nodes node2 kubernetes.io/role=control-plane
kubectl taint node --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

I wonder if those pods in node1(for example) would stop after I run `kubectl label nodes`?

Comment: No, scheduling is already done. Also, you can test this without much efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command to schedule pods on the master nodes

```
kubectl taint node <master-node> node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-
```